# Grammar regex in Sublime/Textmate/Atom

Tags: regex, sublimetext, textmate, atom-editor

In Puppet there are two forms of require:

**Relationship**

```
require foo
```

**Metaparameter**

```
require => 'foo'
```

I want to change the Texmate/Sublime Text/Atom grammar so it can highlight them correctly.

Right now the code looks like this (Atom package, but they all share the same Textmate style regex):

```
{
    'begin': '(?i)\\b(import|include|require)\\b\\s*'
    'beginCaptures':
      '1':
        'name': 'keyword.control.import.include.puppet'
    'end': '(?=\\s|$)'
    'name': 'meta.include.puppet'
}
```

However, this means that `require =>` still gets highlighted:

[image: Example incorrect highlighting]

When the grammar is correct, `require =>` should be the orange color.

How can I change the regex to accommodate this requirement? Does it require a separate rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a negative lookahead:

```
(?!.*=>)\b(import|include|require)\b\s*
```

That will assert that the line doesn't contains `=>` see <kbd>[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nS2uE2/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Try following regex. I know it's lengthy but tries to cover lot of possibilities.

```
(?mi)(?<=\b)(require|import|include)\s+(=>\s*)?('\S+'|[^\s']+)\s*$
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cX0fS0/1) here